# Soft question about mathematical finance-Is it really applicable?

Tags: soft-question, finance

I met with one of my professors today.  For some background, he is a professor in the mathematics department who studies statistics (specifically kernel density estimation and nonparametric curve estimation).  We were talking about other professor’s research, and I mentioned I was interested in stochastic calculus and mathematical finance. He looks at me and says, quietly so no one else can here, “It doesn’t work. You can’t accurately model financial behavior; it just doesn’t work.”

This really got me thinking.  Why did he say this? Surely stochastic processes, like Brownian motion, play a heavy role in mathematical finance.  Unfortunately, it made me second guess studying anything like this.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe *he* can't accurately model financial behaviour. The successful hedge funds clearly can.

Comment: Do hedge funds still use Black Scholes and stochastic calculus techniques? Or have they all switched to machine learning or something instead.

Comment: @littleO I feel like data science and machine learning techniques are dominating right now-pretty much drowning out whatever is left of studying the usual probability models.

Comment: @littleO There's a distinction between modeling to interpolate prices of illiquid stuff from prices of liquid stuff (and to optimally hedge said illiquid stuff with liquid stuff) and modeling to predict future prices and volatility.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Would you mind adding more?

Comment: Sure, although I'm about to go to sleep so I'll be brief and only give one example (maybe will check back and say more tomorrow). If you trade options on something, there's a ton of strikes and maturities, so your position will be very complicated. You need to reduce the dimensionality. Black-Scholesly models are used to express your position in terms of some informative risk factors (the greeks).

Comment: You might have heard of the vol surface, which is a first pass to "correct" the price of options for moneyness and maturity (high implied vol means high price). Most important risk factor is to the level of that surface... all option vols tend to move together as market demand for volatility exposure changes. Or the skew of the surface might change too (eg put side might go up more than call side). You need to know how much money you're going to make/lose if market conditions change.

Comment: And not all those strikes/maturities trade but you might get asked to quote one that doesn't... or you might be doing more structuring kind of work where you're pricing stuff that isn't listed at all. Then your model will tell you what the risk profile of the illiquid thing is and how it fits into your book, and also imply how to hedge it with liquid stuff you can actually buy quickly for a good price.

Comment: @PatrickStevens or they earn their money from something else entirely and it's all a facade..